# Return sublists of List of lists

Tags: python

Well, I have this example:

```
mylist = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

It is a list of lists. I want to keep the first 5 points of each sublist. If it was a simple list I would called `mylist[:5]` and that's all. Now, the simpliest method I could imagine is to iterate through the mylist and copy the first 5 points of each sublist into a new list.

```
newlist = []
for i in mylist:
    newlist.append(i[:5])
```

But what will happen if my list has length 10.000+. Do you know a faster way?

Comment: To process all the lists you have to... process all the lists at least once. So there is no faster way than linear `O(n)` complexity. If you don't need all of the results at once, you could write a function to get a particular sub-list on demand.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, you could do the same using list comprehension so at least it would get a bit shorter.

```
return [x[:5] for x in mylist]
```

Or if making your function a generator instead, you could also yield the individual elements:

```
for x in mylist:
    yield x[:5]
```

Comment: My understanding is that list comprehensions are more efficient than traditional python loops, so it not only makes the code shorter but should be executed more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve it:

```
return map(lambda lst: lst[:5], mylist)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use generators for the inner lists as well, if you are trying to get the process to scale :

```
g = lambda k: (k[i] for i in range(5))
for x in mylist:
    yield g(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

A functional approach:

```
map(operator.itemgetter(slice(0, 5)), mylist)
```